# Continuous Deployment of asp.net app to azure scale sets

Tags: azure

I am working on building a CI CD pipeline of a .net application. I am finished with the CI part and everything is working as expected, the pipeline is releasing an artifact with the website files in it.

Instead of deploying this application to a singular vm, i would like to deploy it on virtual machine scale set.

I understand this is not a direct explicit question, but I am really trying to understand how people do this. I couldn't find any accurate documentation on it.

From my understanding, there are 2 different ways from what I've read.

1. Build an immutable image and push it to VMSS using a built in tasks of the release pipelines
2. Use extension scripts that will push the changes to each vm as decscribed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-install-apps-powershell)